# Issues in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

My issue happens when I click on a Spinner first position (Mens Accessories): it displays only a message and  the cancel Button it does not show the List of Items in alert dilalog.AlertDialog created But list of items not created in Dialog

can anyone solve this problem?if any one solve he is the master in android technology

```
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Resources resources = getResources();
    final String items[] = resources.getStringArray(R.array.bspin);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,items);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0)
            {

            }
            if (position == 1)
            {
                Resources r = getResources();
                final String list[] =  r.getStringArray(R.array.cspin);
                boolean bl[]  = new boolean[list.length];

                AlertDialog.Builder ab1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                ab1.setMessage("Mens Accesories");
                 ab1.setSingleChoiceItems(list,1,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch(which)
                        {
                            case 0:
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+list[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            break;
                            case 1:
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+list[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            case 2:
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+list[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            break;
                            case 3:
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+list[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }

                    }
                });
            ab1.setNeutralButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
                ab1.show();
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i think because in 0th position you are not define anything

Comment: Same result when i am delete 0 position.no output

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
if (position == 0)
            {

            }
```

and replace 1 with 0 like following

```
if (position == 0)
            {
                Resources r = getResources();
                final String list[] =  r.getStringArray(R.array.cspin);
                boolean bl[]  = new boolean[list.length];
```

Comment: if i m replacing with 0 ,same result no output

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
 Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        final String items[] = resources.getStringArray(R.array.bspin);
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,items);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0){

                    Resources r = getResources();
                    final String list[] =  r.getStringArray(R.array.cspin);
                    boolean bl[]  = new boolean[list.length];

                    AlertDialog.Builder ab1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    ab1.setMessage("Mens Accesories");
                     ab1.setSingleChoiceItems(list,1,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch(which)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+list[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                break;
                                case 1:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+list[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                case 2:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+list[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                break;
                                case 3:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+list[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    });
                ab1.setNeutralButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                    ab1.show();
                    }else if(position==1){
//Do as per your need...
}

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i want when i click on spinner menu items then after it open an alert dilouge but if spinner item position is not mentioned then how it will come and it display same alert dilouge to all spinner iitems

Comment: @AnilkumarJohn..I have edited the answer...actually i am not getting your question properly but now i made my final chage...hope it will work for you...

Comment: no its not working must and should you can replace setMessage with setTitle this is right answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this Simplified one.

This also have data which is in Currently Selected Spinner Item.

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Resources resources = getResources();
    final String items[] = resources.getStringArray(R.array.dummy);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,items);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
            String data = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            showMyDialog(position, data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

My showMyDialog method as,

```
private void showMyDialog(int position, String data)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Mens Accesories");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("You clicked Position is : " + position + " and \nData is : " + data);


    // Setting Netural "Cancel" Button
    alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // User pressed Cancel button. Write Logic Here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Cancel",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```